# Powershell Bulk Remove-ADGroupMember

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am looking to carry out a bulk removal of members from multiple groups from an imported CSV file of SAMAccountName, ADGroup. I could just loop through every record in the array (of which there will be 1600 entries) but it would be better if I could collate all of the users that are in a particular group and issue the Remove-ADGroupMember with multiple users.

I'm not sure how to process the data in the array so it appears as ADGroup, MultipleSAMAccountNames - I'm probably missing something obvious.

Example CSV:

```
SAMAccountName, ADGroup
User1, GroupA
User2, GroupA
User3, GroupB
User4, GroupA
```

Example Code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-CSV "Users.csv"
foreach ($User in $Users)
 {
 Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $User.ADGroup -Members $User.SAMAccountName
 }
```

Desired:

```
foreach ($Group in $Users)
     {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $Group.ADGroup -Members $Group.MultipleSAMAccountNames
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Users = Import-CSV "Users.csv"
$Groups = $Users.ADGroup | Sort-Object -Unique

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $Group -Members ($Users | Where-Object { $_.ADGroup -eq $Group }).SamAccountName
}
```

- Gets a unique list of the groups in the CSV.
- Loops through each unique group and uses `Where-Object` to filter `$Users` for any users that match that group, the result of which is then sent to the `-Members` parameter.

Note this is untested code, so use with care.

Comment: Thank you Mark, annoyingly the -WhatIf parameter does not provide enough detail to determine what action it will be taking other than it will perform a SET command on a group - I can run the Where-object command in the debugger which does return the users associated with that group, one per line - I'm not sure how the Remove-ADGroupMember command will handle that as it's expecting a comma separated list or users. I could amend your code to $UsersCSV = ($Users | Where-Object { $_.ADGroup -eq $Group }).SamAccountName - join "," within the loop and pass that variable to the -Members parameter.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the documentation. It doesn't expect it to be a comma separated list, but rather an array of strings, which is what my `where-object` creates for you (its just when an array is output to the console it shows it as one per line).

Comment: I suggest you create a test group to try it against to ensure it does what you expect, particularly as the `-whatif` isn't giving you explicit enough information.

Comment: Thanks Mark, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796058/mark-wragg) beat me to it, but here's my (also untested) solution without the need for a `Where-Object` clause:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# read the CSV file and group the objects by the 'ADGroup' property
$UsersAndGroups = Import-CSV "Users.csv" | Group-Object -Property ADGroup

# loop through the groups
foreach ($group in $UsersAndGroups) {
    # get an array of users belonging to this group
    $accounts = $group.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName -Unique
    # remove them all from the group
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name -Members $accounts
}
```

For testing purposes, add the `-WhatIf` switch at the end of the `Remove-ADGroupMember` command.

Comment: Thank you Theo, I couldn't get your code to work sorry - the $UsersAndGroups variable contained all of the records in one array row - Count, Name, Group - the Name was blank and Group data was along the lines of {@{@{SAMAccountName=joe.bloggs;Group=grp.example} - also the same user was repeated several times.

Comment: @Johnnie Ah, sorry, my mistake.. When copy/pasting I somehow left a `ConvertFrom-Csv` in there. I've corrected it now.